# Why does this Python code work without semaphore on Win11?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

Sum is 0 on Win11 and <>0 on Cygwin

```py
import threading
import os

x = 0;

class Thread1(threading.Thread):       
    def run(self): 
        global x
        for i in range(1,1000000):
            x = x + 1

class Thread2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):  
        global x
        for i in range(1,1000000):
            x = x - 1
t1 = Thread1()
t2 = Thread2()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

print("Sum is "+str(x));
```

I know that if `x` is not locked, the two threads can interfere with each other. But why doesn't this happen on Windows?

Comment: The fact that a race condition exists does not mean that you'll actually see things happen in any unexpected order. It depends on the OS's scheduler.

Comment: it may be optimizing those operations to atomic INC and DEC instructions, which may not be atomic on other platforms, or are unoptimized.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that one thread is running pretty much the instant you start it.
You can use a barrier to make sure both threads start looping at the same time.
You can also use += i and -= i for better display. (1 race causes more difference)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects

```py
import threading

b = threading.Barrier(2, timeout=5)

x = 0;

class Thread1(threading.Thread):       
    def run(self): 
        global x
        b.wait()
        for i in range(int(1e5)):
            x += i

class Thread2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):  
        global x
        b.wait()
        for i in range(int(1e5)):
            x -= i
t1 = Thread1()
t2 = Thread2()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

print("Sum is "+str(x));
```